# Can You Update Fields via Dot Notation?

Tags: soql, lead-conversion, childrecords

I have two custom objects, Subscription and Product User. Product User is a child object of Subscription in a Master-Detail relationship. In a trigger I have built, I want to update a lookup field (to Account) on the Subscription when certain actions occur. I'm trying to do it by updating the Subscription__r.Account__c "field" that exists on the Product User object. Obviously, the field isn't actually on the Product User, but rather the Subscription. Is it possible to update a field by transversing an object like this? It doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
// store a list of Product User records, including the Subscription Account Id, looking up to a Lead stored in the Lead:Contact mapping
List < Product_User__c > listProductUser = [SELECT Lead__c, Contact__c, * * Subscription__r.Account__c, * * External_Id__c
FROM Product_User__c
WHERE Lead__c IN: mapLeadIdContactId.keySet()];

// iterate through all Product User records that lookup to a Lead
for (Product_User__c p: listProductUser) {

    p.Contact__c = mapLeadIdContactId.get(p.Lead__c);
    // this update of External Id is just to check that my mapping is pulling a value
    // it does as this field gets populated, but Subscription__r.Account__c does not; they should be the same
    p.External_Id__c = mapLeadIdAccountId.get(p.Lead__c);
    p.Subscription__r.Account__c = mapLeadIdAccountId.get(p.Lead__c);
}

update listProductUser;
```

Do I just need to find a way to update the Subscription directly, and can't do it via transversing the parent object?

Let me know if I need to provide more context. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, but as you already have the `Id`, building the list is fairly simple:

```
Map<Id, Subscription__c> subscriptionMap = new Map<Id, Subscription__c>();
for (ProductUser productUser : productUsers)
{
    Subscription__c subscription = new Subscription__c(
        Id = productUser.Subscription__c,
        Account__c = leadIdToAccountId.get(productUser.Lead__c)
    );
    subscriptionMap.put(subscription.Id, subscription);
}
List<Subscription__c> subscriptions = subscriptionMap.values();
try
{
    update subscriptions;
}
catch (DmlException dmx)
{
    // typical handling maps errors back to the source record
    // here we are updating children we would map Child Id to Parent instead
    // if we were updating the parent so we map to of Parent Id to List<Child>
    for (Integer i = 0; i < dmx.getNumDml(); i++)
    {
        // now ordering is important
        // assume some Map<Id, Account> accountMap exists
        Account parent = accountMap.get(subscriptions[dmx.getDmlIndex(i)].Account__c);
        parrent.addError(dmx);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response guys. This worked perfectly.

Could you explain the try-catch part - what are some potential issues that can occur on cross object updates via Apex?

Comment: So let's say just for instance you are trying to update a subscription and for some reason the Account lookup (or some other data) fails a validation rule. You will get a DMLException, which you then need to handle. Typically you just map the error back to the source record, I'll add in a canonical example.